# Foxpro delete - pack "file must be open exclusively"

Tags: visual-foxpro

When I LOCATE a record in Visual foxpro,

LOCALTE for studentID = 1
IF FOUND()
 DELETE
 PACK
ENDIF

In the PACK command, error message "File must be open exclusively"

Have I close all table before PACK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get exclusive use, you need to tell it so when you open...

```
select YourTable
use YourTable EXCLUSIVE
PACK
use YourTable SHARED
```

However, packing the table all the time is not efficient and there is an easier way to "ignore" records marked for deletion..

Look into

```
SET DELETED ON
SET DELETED OFF
```

Set deleted "ON" means HIDE ANY RECORDS that are marked for deletion.  So you don't need to pack each time.  set delete "OFF" means SHOW ALL records, even those marked for deletion.

But also, having EXCLUSIVE use can cause an issue in a multi-user environment if others are using the table too.  You would typically have some database maintenance routine that would try to check for exclusive use on tables and do them all during a cleanup process.

Answer (score 0):

Also, LOCATE/FOUND is sort of old-school, once you have the table open exclusively just do:

```
delete from mytable where studentid=1
pack
```